# git CLI output loses colours after some time while using MS Terminal with Powershell Core

Tags: git, powershell, terminal

My problem is: when I launch a fresh tab of Powershell x64 (Core 7.2.0) in Microsoft Terminal (1.14.1962.0), git (2.29.2.windows.3) commands returns coloured output in console:
[image]

After some time and some commands, the output of git becomes the following:
[image]

I thought that the problem is in MS Terminal or Powershell Core, but `ls` command is still returns output in colour, and I never seen this output non-coloured!

Maybe somebody has already faced the problem?

Comment: After colors stopped working and you open a new tab, does it give exactly the same output but with colors? What does `git config --get color.status` say in both tabs?

Comment: @svlasov I checked this. The output is the same except colours. git config command returns true in both tabs.

Comment: Something in shell environment changes that makes git think this is not an interractive terminal and disable the colors. If you want quick and dirty solution, you can force the colors to be used always via `git config --global color.status always`. Can you try to run `echo $TTY` in both tabs?

Comment: @svlasov ```echo $TTY ``` returns nothing in both tabs. Thanks, ```git config --global color.status always``` healed broken colours in 1st tab.